# Laravel - generate unique order number

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I'm currently trying to generate a unique order number when the user reaches the create method. The order numbers are generated like this in the seed and need to look like this as well

**Seed**

```
foreach(range(1,25) as $index)
    {
        DB::table('orders')->insert([

            'user_id' => rand(1,25),
            'order_nr' => '#' . sprintf("%08d", $index),
            'price_sum' => $faker->randomNumber($nbDigits = 4, $strict = false) . '.' . $faker->randomNumber($nbDigits = 2, $strict = false),
            'status' => $faker->randomElement(['paid', 'pending', 'failed']),
            'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
            'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),

        ]);
    }
```

The order numbers look like this `#00000001` or `#00000002`. Now when the user reaches the create method in my controller a new unique order number in this sequence needs to be created. How can I achieve that? The controller currently looks like this:

```
 public function create()
{
    $order = new Order;

    $order->user_id = Auth()->id();
    $order->order_nr = 


    dd($order);


    return view('steps.order');
}
```

It needs to check the latest order number and create one with +1 on that order number. Say for instance there are 25 orders and the last one is #00000025 the one that needs to be created next needs to be #00000026. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try doing as following

```
$order = new Order;

$order->user_id = Auth()->id();
$latestOrder = App\Order::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->first();
$order->order_nr = '#'.str_pad($latestOrder->id + 1, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$order->save();
```

Here I am assuming that the id is auto-incrementing. See the [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) method for more details

Comment: That did it for me. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure about this solution. Let's assume, I have following orders:
`[1 => order1, 2 => order2, 3 => order3, ]`; Your orders are sent as an email to the customers who made this order or something. The link to the order would be www.blah/order3 . But if I would delete the 3rd order and it was in for example in client's mail box. I would make new order then and it would also have the same link, because you would create order with the same name. And the link would then be incorrect. I do not know if it is your usecase but it's good to have it in mind. @RainierLaan

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood, by why not use MySQL to achieve this using `INT(8) ZEROFILL` on your desired id column be it an auto increment or reference to a foreign key

Comment: @Epsilon47 When the user gets to a screen to see a sum of their order they get 2 options. To either don't pay which means that it deletes the entire order and they get the option to pay which fills the rest of the values and makes it permanent. When the user paid. There is no way for them to delete an order out of the system. Because why would they want to in the first place? Their orders only get deleted when the user decised to delete his/her account. Until then the orders will stay. If this the right way to think or even handle this?

Comment: @RainierLaan I think you should not delete orders at all or consider using soft deletes (I am not sure how the ids behave in this case). Because you can get to the problem I wrote. So if you want to delete them I would use random number, not ordered, or I would not delete them. Or before storing I would check if the order with this id already does not exist.

Comment: @RainierLaan Or you can use another column in your table like `is_active` which will be boolean and true by default. If somebody deletes their account you could make it false. Just a thought.

Answer (score 5):

Use the auto column id value of your rows to generate the order number. However, do not create an extra column for your order number, because this would give you an unnormalized DB, since the order-column is completely dependent of the id column.

Instead, add this method to you `order` model

```
public function get_order_number()
{
    return '#' . str_pad($this->id, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

If your last order had the id `5` and you would delete it, then the next order would have the id `6`.

The only possible exception is if you create orders within an transaction. If a transaction is rolled back, the associated order id would be skipped.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Laravel ID generator](https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-custom-id-generator).

First Install it: 
`composer require haruncpi/laravel-id-generator`

Import the class in your controller.

```
use Haruncpi\LaravelIdGenerator\IdGenerator;
```

Now simply use it

```
$prefix = "#";  
$id = IdGenerator::generate(['table' => 'your_table_name', 'length' => 9, 'prefix' =>$prefix]);
```

Output

```
#00000001
#00000002
#00000003
...
```

Comment: Just to comment that this package seems to bug as of Laravel 8 at least if the field to fill, isn't the id field in the db but a custom one. The package doesn't use the actual id number of the ID field but instead it starts from 1. Then once it reaches 10, it starts again from 1 generating non-unique IDs

Answer (score 2):

There is a **problem in reading the maximum** id and increment it.
In heavy servers or parallel requests, two requests may read the same max(id) from MySQL.

The best way to create unique sequence number is use a sequence table with just one auto increment field.

1. First insert new record in the sequence table.
2. Then read the last inserted id from db by LAST_INSERT_ID() MySQL function.
3. At last you can remove old records lower than your id.

Laravel way:

```
$id = DB::table('seq_foo')->insertGetId(['id' => null]);
DB::table('seq_foo')->where('id', '<', $id)->delete();
```

$id is your unique sequence number.

Answer (score 1):

You may try with this:

```
public function generateOrderNR()
{
    $orderObj = \DB::table('orders')->select('order_nr')->latest('id')->first();
    if ($orderObj) {
        $orderNr = $orderObj->order_nr;
        $removed1char = substr($orderNr, 1);
        $generateOrder_nr = $stpad = '#' . str_pad($removed1char + 1, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    } else {
        $generateOrder_nr = '#' . str_pad(1, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    return $generateOrder_nr;
}
```

You can generate `order_nr` by using this: `$this->generateOrderNR();` in your `create()` function.

In addition `mt_rand()` is 4 times faster than `rand()` you may use this for better user experience.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a better solution:

```
$paynowbillprefix1="ADDON-";
$paynowbillprefix1=strlen($paynowbillprefix1);
$query2 = "select gen_id from user_cart_addon order by id desc limit 0, 1";
$exec2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query2) or die ("Error in Query2".mysqli_error());
$res2 = mysqli_fetch_array($exec2);
$num2 = mysqli_num_rows($exec2);
$billnumber = $res2["gen_id"];
$billdigit=strlen($billnumber);
if ($billnumber == '')
{
    $billnumbercode ='ADDON-'.'1';
}
else
{
    $billnumber = $res2["gen_id"];
    $billnumbercode = substr($billnumber,$paynowbillprefix1, $billdigit);
    $billnumbercode = intval($billnumbercode);
    $billnumbercode = $billnumbercode + 1;
    $maxanum = $billnumbercode;   
    $billnumbercode = 'ADDON-'.$maxanum;
}
```